# NullPointerException "at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getNonDecorViews"

Tags: android, junit

I am facing this issue in Junit. I have created an Android application that refers the Library project.
I have written an Android Test Project that runs on the Android application project.

I get the following error while running the test cases:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getNonDecorViews(ViewFetcher.java:188)
> at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getAllViews(ViewFetcher.java:112)
> at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.clickableItemsExist(Waiter.java:164)
> at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForClickableItems(Waiter.java:150)
> at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnView(Solo.java:787)
> at com.mycompany.myproject.test.LoginActivityInstrumentation.enterSessionPin(LoginActivityInstrumentation.java:149)
> com.mycompany.myproject.test.LoginActivityTest.testEnterButtonCase1(LoginActivityTest.java:174)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
> at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
> at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
> at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
> at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
> at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
> ```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed after updating robotium.jar to 3.2.1